# "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js

I am a beginner with VueJs and this is my first App:

```js
import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
    
const myApp = createApp(App)
myApp.use(BootstrapVue)
myApp.mount('#app')
```

And when I save, nothing appears in my browser and it show this message in the Command:

```
warning  in ./src/main.js

"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
```

Comment: are you using vue 3?

Comment: Yes Vue Cli3 , it worked fine the first time but when i import the BootstrapVue the command showed the message above

Comment: please share your package.json content

Comment: `"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.16.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-rc.10",
    "vue-loader-v16": "npm:vue-loader@^16.0.0-alpha.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
  },`

Comment: how did you setup the project for the first time?

Comment: npm install -g @ vue/cli , i think maybe i have vue Cli 4 that's why because bootstrap don't support it yet

Comment: you're installing the vue version 3 which is in beta version and using a library (i mean bootstrap-vue) which is built using vue 2, if you don't have much progress in your project i could suggest the right setup

Comment: FYI, Vue CLI and Vue are entirely different projects so try not to confuse their version numbers. Vue CLI v4 is stable. Vue v2 is stable. Vue v3 is still in beta

Comment: Or you can use raw bootstrap and use bootstrap component with class. I found one UI library have beta support for vue 3, ant design(https://2x.antdv.com/docs/vue/introduce/). Remember to look at the version 2.0.0-beta, 1.x is for vue 2. Have fun!

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Bootstrap-Vue does not yet support Vue 3.
So if you want to use Bootstrap-Vue you will have to stick with Vue 2 for now.

In general, most of the libraries don't support Vue 3 yet, so I would suggest waiting a bit longer before using it until the ecosystem has caught up.

#### Explanation

The reason this is happening is because in Vue 2, Vue provides a default export `export default vue`, which allows BootstrapVue to use `import Vue from 'vue'`.

However, in Vue 3 this has changed, and Vue does no longer provide a default export, and instead uses named exports. So when BootstrapVue uses the following line `import Vue from 'vue'`, the error occurs.

Comment: i came across this problem using vue2

Comment: Still the same. :( 2021-07-19

Comment: Doesn't really explain how to fix it

Comment: @ak22 `So if you want to use Bootstrap-Vue you will have to stick with Vue 2 for now.`, not sure how that isn't a solution?

Comment: Frankly all I did was create a new project (not bootstrap but quasar) and I copied over a .js file from a previous project used "import Vue from 'vue'".  My package.json has vue at 2.6.12 but still get this error. So, not sure what I need to do. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The latest version of Quasar uses Vue 3, so that's likely the issue with why your previous code doesn't work. Why your `package.json` says `2.6.12` I don't know. But I would check which version of `Quasar` is installed. If it's `Quasar 1.x.x`, then it's Vue 2, if it's `Quasar 2.x.x` then it's Vue 3. Otherwise open up a new Question here on Stackoverflow, and someone might have an answer.

Comment: You are right when I installed quasar it had migrated to v2 which uses vue3. I probably changed the .json file to v2 thinking that quasar was still at v1.

Comment: Where is the solution?

Comment: don't loose time this is not  the answer just look the bellow one

Answer (score 50):

`import * as Vue from 'vue'`

this works for me

Comment: lol. Why is this not documented anywhere? (thank you)

Comment: haha, who knows, these small things always confuse people

Comment: Can you please extend your answer? Some more code e.g. your working code in main.js can help more people I think.

Comment: good, I will pay attention to it!

Comment: After i did that i got this error `export 'component' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'`

Comment: perfect, idk what kind of import happen there just no warning after this applied (works for laravel 9, vue 3)

Comment: @Vipertecpro remove the single quotes or see bellow

Answer (score 20):

I was getting the warning

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
```

I'm using Vue 3 but the code I'm studying is Vue 2.

My code Vue 2 in main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
    
Vue.config.productionTip = false
    
new Vue ({
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

So I needed to create a Vue instance with the following code Vue 2:

```js
export const eventBus = new Vue ()
```

Then I received the error code, which I resolved by correcting the code that looked like this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

export const eventBus = createApp(App)

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 6):

hi i am using laravel 9 mix and vue 3 here is my code app.js

```
// app.js
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import test from './components/Test.vue';

createApp({
    components: { test }
}).mount('#app')
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue();
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case, I use webpack and vue2.

I use vue-loader to handle .vue file . I found I installed vue-loader v17 which requires vue3, so I uninstall it and `npm i vue-loader@15`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this looks like it was caused by some sort of corrupt node module somewhere. I solved the problem by running

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

In my project root directory. This deletes your node_modules folder. Then I reran

```
yarn install
```

or

```
npm install
```

and the problem was fixed. Hope this helps someone else. Also, many have noted the differences between vue 3 and vue 2 dependencies, I'm not sure those are still relevant in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

On Vue 3 applications you have to use the following connection Vuex store

store.js

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

export default createStore({
    state: {
    },
    mutations: {
    },
    actions: {
    }
})
```

main.js

```
import store from '@/store';
...
app.use(store);
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the current responses fixed the issue for me though mine was a little different; I control the component that was failing and I know it was made with Vue3.

In case someone hits this issue but with a component they control, it COULD be that you removed the `setup` attribute from your components `<script>` tag.

So changing

```
<script lang="ts">
```

to

```
<script setup lang="ts">
```

fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the wrong `resolve.alias` directive in `webpack.config.js`, which set `'vue'` to `'vue/dist/vue.js'` instead of `'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'`;

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vuex, running:

`npm remove vuex`

`npm i vuex@3`

should fix this problem.

Comment: You can't use vuex@3 unless you use vue 3 though?

Comment: @lloydcox no, version 3 in vuex isn't related to Vue 3.

Answer (score -1):

```
const Vue = require('vue')
const AppImport = Vue.createApp("dev-axios");
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
AppImport.use(VueAxios,axios);
```

Comment: Please add some explanations.

Answer (score -5):

If you're just after the styles you can simply put

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

into your app.js file and it will work without errors.