# Vue.js 3: Cannot import Vue global object

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli, vuejs3

I'm going crazy trying to reconcile the Vue 3 CLI output into something that works with various tutorials and plugins that all use the Vue object, as in `Vue.createApp(...`. In my project, I can use

```
import {createApp} from 'vue';
createApp(...
```

but `import Vue from 'vue';` results in Vue still being undefined. I have Vue 3 installed via NPM. Clearly there is something critical that I don't understand about NPM imports, how could the `{createApp}` import work if importing the whole module does not work?

From package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.22.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "d3": "^6.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  },
```

Here is my temporary main.js. This prints 'undefined' followed by the correct createApp function definition:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {createApp} from 'vue';
console.log(Vue);   
console.log(createApp);
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63768491/export-default-imported-as-vue-was-not-found-in-vue

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're working with CDN `Vue` is available as global variable which could be used to create instance by calling the method `createApp` like `Vue.createApp({...})`, but if you're working with a bundler which uses npm modules, there no `Vue` object imported from  `vue` module so you should import `createApp` from it to create a new instance like :

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue';
let app=new createApp({...})
app.use(somePlugin)
app.mount("#app")
```

for more details please check the migration guide of [global API](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#global-api-application-instance)

Comment: Thanks. The reason I was looking into this is because one of the dependencies I am using, vue3-apexcharts, is throwing an error saying there is no global Vue object. I guess I'll file an issue for that project.

Comment: @Gregorio246 according to this [comment](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts/issues/288#issuecomment-706344384) apex charts is not compatible with vue 3

Comment: The component that he talks about in that comment was released about a week ago, which is what I am using.

Comment: You're talking about this [one](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: This works for `createApp` but it doesn't work with things like `Vue.set`. How do you call that when there's not Vue object?

Comment: `Vue.set` is not available in vue 3, it used in vue 2 to solve some reactivity issue