# Typescript - TS1192: Module has no default export

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, npm, webpack

I am developing application in vue3 with typescript support.
I do not know why but every time I compile code with `npm` it shows me this:

`TS1192: Module '"/home/admin/Desktop/projects/myProj/frontend/components/SectionTitle.vue"' has no default export.`

by the way I have enabled **allowSyntheticDefaultImports** in my tsconfig.json

```json
"compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "removeComments": true,
        "lib": ["DOM", "ES2020", "ES2020.Promise"],
        "module": "es2020",
        "target": "es2015",
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    },
```

```
webpack version: 5.50.0
typescript version: 2.8.3
```

How do I export components

```
export default defineComponent({
...
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install typescript 4.3.2

`package.json`

```json
"typescript": "4.3.2",
```

Comment: That didn’t work for me, could it be because I am using @vue/composition-api with vue2? If so, do you have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const component = defineComponent({
    
    })
    
export default component;
```

Comment: tried, but didn't work. I am getting the same result

Comment: How are you importing vue?
Btw, I haven't used vue. But I know typescript.

Comment: ```import { createApp } from "vue";```

Comment: See if this helps you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64653481/4932908