# export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' in Vue 3 and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3

I am going to create a Laravel 8 + Vue JS 3 hybrid project.I have already setup everything, but when I `npm run watch`, there is an error like the one below. I have tried various ways to look at some forums but still error. Can anyone help me?

> **WARNING in ./resources/js/components/index.js 6:2-15**
> **export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'** (possible exports: BaseTransition, Comment, Fragment, KeepAlive, Static, Suspense, Teleport, Text, Transition, TransitionGroup, callWithAsyncErrorHandling, callWithErrorHandling, camelize,....

**./js/components/ExampleComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**./js/components/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Card from './Card';
import Button from './Button';

// Components global.
[
  Card,
  Button,
].forEach(Component => {
  Vue.component(Component.name, Component)
})
```

**./js/app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import './components';

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

   if(!mix.inProduction()) {
      mix.sourceMaps();
      mix.webpackConfig({ devtool: 'source-map'})
      .options({
         processCssUrls: false
      });
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63768491/export-default-imported-as-vue-was-not-found-in-vue)

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be like :

**./js/app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import { createApp } from 'vue';

import components from  './components';
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue'

let app=createApp(ExampleComponent)
app.use(components)


app.mount("#app")
```

**./js/components/index.js**

this is a plugin that register the components globally

```
import Card from './Card';
import Button from './Button';

// Components global.

export default {
  install: (app, options) => {
    [
  Card,
  Button,
].forEach(Component => {
  app.component(Component.name, Component)
})
  }
}
```