# How can I install Bootstrap into this Vue.js project using vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-5

I have a Vue project I'm building on, following a tutorial. This project uses Vue Router and I am trying to use Bootstrap. This is the current layout:

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

**index.js**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import MovieDetail from '../views/MovieDetail.vue'


const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/movie/:id',
    name: 'Movie Detail',
    component: MovieDetail
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

I've tried changing the following in **Main.js** to initialise Bootstrap:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { BootstrapVue} from 'bootstrap-vue'

createApp(App).use(router, BootstrapVue).mount('#app')
```

I am getting the warning: ""export 'default' (reexported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'". What do I need to do in order to get BootStrap working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63768491/export-default-imported-as-vue-was-not-found-in-vue)

Comment: @Hiws Potentially, I saw this but figured it's now compatible with Vue 3? Is there a way to downgrade Vue version, as Bootstrap would be a massive help for my project?

Comment: BootstrapVue is not compatible with Vue 3 yet, you can track the progress [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196). If you want to use BootstrapVue you'll have to downgrade to Vue 2, whether that's possible in an existing project I don't know. But if it's a relatively new project, you could simply create a new one and copy your code over. If you want to stick with Vue 3 you'll have to use base Bootstrap, which might require some additional work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap by linking bootstrap css in **head** blocks in
'index.html' which file is located on the root directory of your project.

And make sure that 'bootstrap.min.css' file is located on the **static** folder

> 

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" />
```