# Adding bootstrap5 to vue cli project

Tags: bootstrap-5, vue-cli

I installed Bootstrap Vue as follows:
npm install bootstrap-vue
then i add in main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, BootstrapVueIcons } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router.js'

Vue.config.productionTip =false

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
```

But I got the error in cmd:

export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63768491/export-default-imported-as-vue-was-not-found-in-vue)

Comment: My question is why not found (import Vue) in vue?

Comment: For now, the bootstrap plugin only works with vue 2, I guess your project uses Vue 3, that's why your getting this error. (I found the answer googling your error msg, you're supposed to show some research work before asking a question. I won't downvote because that would bring your reputation to 1 but be careful, others would not hesitate)