# vue-chartjs can't import data from vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I get this error after compiling my Vue 2 project:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vue-chartjs/dist/index.js 85:11-26
"export 'defineComponent' was not found in 'vue'
```

The line in the file above that is causing this behavior is:

```js
import { defineComponent, shallowRef, ref, watch, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount, toRaw, h, isProxy } from 'vue';
```

All of these imports cause the same error. This happens after I upgrade vue-chartjs from version 3.5.1 to version 4.1.1 (before it works perfectly). I'm looking for ideas on what might be causing this.

The versions of used dependencies are:

```
- "chart.js": "^3.8.0"
- "vue": "^2.6.14"
- "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.1"
```

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a snippet. This happens only on a project which is in use at work. If I try this on a clean project, it compiles perfectly. The Internet is almost void in regard to information on Vue, so I'm just looking for any idea.

Anything you can think of that could cause this, please share. Even the dumbest idea may help, I've been scouring the Internet for days and I can't find anything. This is getting super frustrating, all I wanted to do was upgrade chart.js and it's taking me days, lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are trying to import the lib like so:

```js
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
```

This won't work for you since you are using Vue2. To use the Vue wrapper with Vue2 you will need to import from `'vue-chartjs/legacy'`. In here they have support for Vue V2 and then your application should compile just fine.

Correct import for you:

```js
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs/legacy'
```

Comming from their [readme](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs#how-to-use)

Comment: Right, there is also a migration guide for that: https://vue-chartjs.org/migration-guides/#tree-shaking

Comment: I'm not trying to import from vue-chartjs (that works fine). It's a file in node_modules/vue-chartjs and it's importing from node_modules/vue. So, it's a default setting. What makes it even more frustrating is that the dependencies are also automatically set and same versions of these packages work on a clean project...

Comment: In that case will need a reproducable sample to help you further. Because the only way I can remotly get that error is by importing the wrong way by importing form vue-chartjs itself instead of vue-chartjs/legacy

Comment: @LeeLenalee Actually, this is the correct answer. An import was made by someone else who uses charts in another component and that caused many errors. Adding /legacy to that import solved the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually coming from the fact that you're using a Vue3 specific version. As explained here: ["export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63768491/8816585)

Checking the releases page of `vue-chartjs`, we can see that `v4.0.0` had a breaking change of migrating to Vue3: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/releases/tag/v4.0.0

Hence why the v4 is causing such problem. Stay at `v3.5.1` (22 august 2020) or below if you're stuck with a Vue2 usage.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think that's not it, though. 

Version 4.0.0 is when support for Vue 3 became available, but in the vue-chartjs documentation it says it supports both Vue 2 & 3. Also, on a clean project I was able to make it work with vue-chartjs 4.1.1 & Vue 2.6.14 without any workarounds.